# Grep pattern from file (list) into same line

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have two files (see below) and want to grep the patterns in file 1 from file 2 (2 columns). I think it is really easy but I could not find any clue how to grep the matches to the same line

```
File1
ABC
DEF
GHI

File 2
ABC SeqX
ABC SeqY
ABC SeqP
DEF SeqW
DEF SeqO
GHI SeqR
GHI Seql
```

The output should look like this:

```
    ABC SeqX SeqY SeqP
    DEF SeqW SeqO
    GHI SeqR Seql
```

I know it has to be something like: `grep -f file 1 file2 > output`

Comment: Your difficulty is not in grepping, it's in turning 3 lines `ABC SeqX` `ABC SeqY` `ABC SeqP` into one line `ABC SeqX SeqY SeqP`. You need awk or perl for that.

Comment: Whats the point of file1? You can produce the output you posted solely from reading file2. If it has a purpose then [edit] your question so the example you posted demonstrates that purpose - right now it looks like all you have for answers are solutions to a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with awk yes, not as_is with grep

```
awk 'FNR==NR { Ls[$1];next}
     ( $1 in Ls) { Ds[ $1] = Ds[ $1] " " $2 }
     END { for( L in Ls ) print L Ds[ L] }
     ' File1 File2
```

Comment: sorry small typo error, `LS` in *END* section  was in fact `Ls`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, NeronLeVelu!

Answer (score 0):

Short `awk` solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2; next}{if($1 in a) print $1a[$i]}' file2 file1
```

The output:

```
ABC SeqX SeqY SeqP
DEF SeqW SeqO
GHI SeqR Seql
```